# Is it possible to disable the one2many focus in odoo when a line is being edited?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

When a line is being edited in one2many list the fields move around , is it possible to keep the same display that have when the line is not on focus.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail to this question? What do you mean by move around?

Comment: i mean the one2many row becomes on focus